# J2ME nokia s40 development

Tags: java-me, nokia

I am using S40 SDK to develop my application.My application requires to communicate with files stored on memory card.But I am helpless that how to put the files on memory card in SDK ?
I am using Eclipse IDE for developing application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `<SDK installation directory>\bin\Storage\<instance identifier>` is where the files are stored by the emulator.. Instance identifier is visible in the title area of the emulator application. It is a number that looks like a phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put files on the memory card within your application?  You need to read about [JSR75 FileConnection](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/).

Comment: No,As i am trying my application on S40 SDK,so where do i put my files on computer so that i can access them through the following link"file:///SDCard/",now don't answer that put them on memory card.

Comment: You can't hard code the file path for your desktop.  You should use only whatever file paths are available, find this out using FileSystemRegistry.listRoots().  Perhaps the system property System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard") might help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following links to get more info:

- [FileConnection API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/82644083-2f4b-4775-a292-c02d6bf5be57/Introduction_To_The_FileConnection_API_v1_1.zip.html)
- [File Connection](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-connection-using-j2me-api-jsr-75.html) Using J2ME api JSR 75
- [Getting Started](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/) with the FileConnection APIs

One more info: Make sure your device supports the FileConnection API.